# How to access Mongo database keys to render values in Haml view with MongoMapper in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongomapper

I'm having a hard time rendering a view in Haml,using MongoMapper for a small Sinatra app I'm working on. 
I have this here which I know the query is not bad:

```
get '/admin' do
  protected!
  @title = "admin"

  @total_items = Item.all(:order=>:itemtype.desc)

  haml :admin, :locals => @total_items
end
```

Now, the problem is , I'm trying to use the @total_items instance variable in my Haml view to be able to output the keys in an ordered list after retrieving each item with the loop:

```
%div 
  %img     
  - @total_items.each do |item|
  %h3= item
```

and I'm stuck.How do I access the keys? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your code at hand:

If you use instance variables you don't need to use `:locals`. They are accessible in your views anyway. So either use `total_items` and make use of `:locals` or use `@total_items` and access them as that in your views. BTW, `:locals` are used like that:

```
haml  :admin, :locals => {:items => total_items}
```

then you can access in admin.haml your `total_items` as `items`

Back to your question: In your admin.haml file there is a small error that is easy to fix: Make sure you get the indentation right. After all this is what haml is about:

```
%div 
  %img     
  -items.each do |item| # I use the above mentioned :locals with items instead of total_items
    %h3= item
```

Edit:
You could even keep it more simple by querying the items from your view:

```
%div 
  %img     
  -Item.all(:order=>:itemtype.desc).each do |item|
    %h3= item
```

PS: What is the `%img` tag good for? It's not used in your example.

Comment: I tried these too before and with the query in the view I get:

Comment: <item:0x00000001c27260></item:0x00000001c27260> The item memory id (is that it?)

Comment: The closest thing that I got would give me the results from the database but I can't access individual keys and values. I don't know how and the other thing is the value comes before the key like this:

Comment: <h3>
[#
<item "m"="" size:="" 15.0,="" price:="" "t-shirt",="" itemtype:="" "panelblock.jpg",="" image:="" d.",="" john="" by="" made="" design="" "cool="" desc:="" bson::objectid('4f67e49e91ab7b22b7000001'),="" _id:="">]</item>
</h3>

Comment: why is it backwards like that? It's fine in the database. And it's not that Mongo queries are complicated. I did the same thing not long ago in Python and it was the easiest thing. But now in Ruby, I'm having a hard time. Well, I'm learning the language at the same time.

Comment: sorry, forgot the key. But you figured it out yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

So, what I'm doing is this and it works perfectly:

```
%div      
-Item.all.each do |item|
%ul
  %li= item[:itemtype]
  %li= item[:desc]
  %li= item[:size]
  %li= item[:price]
  %li= item[:image]
```

Comment: Yes it does work. I thought I tried that yesterday. There was something I was doing wrong.